# A simple mail server in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, email, smtp, pop3

I'm trying make one simple mail server to receive email and print on the screen using sockets in C++. I already make the program, all looks great, but don't works. The socket and threads works great, just login with netcat or telnet to see the that works, but when i try send a email to program, nothing happens.

I think i'm do it wrong in the process function. See that...

```
void process(int new_sd, void *threadid) {
    int tid = (long) threadid;

    ssize_t bytes_recieved;
    char incomming_data_buffer[1000];

    while (1) {
        bytes_recieved = recv(new_sd, incomming_data_buffer, 1000, 0);

        //    if (bytes_recieved == 0) cout << "host shut down." << endl ;
        if (bytes_recieved == -1)cout << "Recieve Error! :(" << endl ;
        incomming_data_buffer[bytes_recieved] = '\0';

        trimwhitespace(incomming_data_buffer);

        cout << "|" << incomming_data_buffer << "|" << endl;

        if (!strcmp(incomming_data_buffer, "QUIT")) {
            close(new_sd);
            break;
        } else {
            send_text(new_sd, "OK \n");
        }
    }
}
```

The complete source code is here: http://pastebin.com/vLH8dSAj
To compile on Linux: g++ -lm mail.cpp -o mail

Thanks!

Comment: By "nothing happens", what do you mean?

Comment: I'm running the program in the 110 port, the POP port and when i sent one e-mail with my smtp server nothing happens, but exists a communication with netcat or telnet.

Comment: Have you tried using tcpdump for port 110 between those machines?

Comment: When i listen the port 110 with tcpdump, i can see the packages incoming, but my program show me nothing.

Comment: There isn't, by any chance, another mail server on that machine "grabbing" the packets?

Comment: I think not, but when have a other program listening on 110 port, my program show 'Bind Error'. Via netcat i can communicate with the program.

Comment: What about firewall settings?

Comment: Firewall is great becouse works ok with netcat...

Answer (score 2):

POP3 is a protocol (read [RFC 1939](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939)), so you have to implement it in order use it. After connecting, the other side won't send you anything until you send the greeting message ("+OK your message here").

After that, you must establish a POP "conversation" with the remote client.

Also, POP is used for retrieving messages from a server, so a client will connect to your proccess and try to download messages.

You have to implement the SMTP protocol (read [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)) in order to receive messages sent to you. SMTP is also a protocol, so you must implement it if you want the other side to send you the data.